# create dask local cluster and share it among different Jupiter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dask, jupyter-lab, dask-distributed

For Dask on a single machine, I would need a global Memory limit. Since i am running/testing a lot of dask application. I created a separate process

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(memory_limit='12GB')
```

And try to connect to it in another process using

```
client = Client('127.0.0.1:38719')
```

However, this line stagnates there.. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: You could also investigate running `dask-scheduler` on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to write the scheduler file that contains connection information:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(memory_limit='12GB')
client.write_scheduler_file("dask_scheduler.json")
```

In a different notebook, you would use:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(scheduler_file='dask_scheduler.json')
```